# Routing error in devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have updates my `route.rb` like:-

```
devise_for :authorizes 
  devise_scope :authorizes  do
  get '/alogin' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  get '/alogout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end

devise_for :hrs 
  devise_scope :hrs  do
  get '/hlogin' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  get '/hlogout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end

devise_for :employes 
  devise_scope :employes  do
  get '/elogin' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  get '/elogout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

**ERROR**

`Could not find devise mapping for path "/alogin". This may happen for two reasons:`

```
 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end
 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `devise_scope`, you should use singular for your model, i.e. `:authorize` (not `:authorizes`)

Just try the following code:

```
devise_for :authorizes 
  devise_scope :authorize  do
  get '/alogin' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  get '/alogout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end

devise_for :hrs 
  devise_scope :hr  do
  get '/hlogin' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  get '/hlogout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end

devise_for :employes 
  devise_scope :employe  do
  get '/elogin' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  get '/elogout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```